# How can I use crypto++ without read/write a key file?

Tags: c++, rsa, crypto++

I'm using Crypto++ RSA api to encrypt and decrypt something, RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Encryptor and RSAES_OAEP_SHA_Decryptor both need a file which stores the pub/pri key。

:( , but I need to store the keys in my C++ code variables, any way to avoid accessing a file?

Or is there any better lib than Crypto++?

Comment: Storing a private key in your program is a bad idea if you intend to distribute the program to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

A cursory glance at the user guide and API docs suggests you should be able to replace the FileSource with a [StringSource](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_string_source.html#a86185516e7339e3a6192be9b88493a00).

Answer (score 0):

The Crpyto++ [Keys and Formats](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Keys_and_formats) wiki page covers this in depth. You can use `DEREncodePrivateKey`, `DEREncodePublicKey`, `BERDecodePrivateKey`, and `BERDecodePublicKey`. Here's the brief tour with two examples.

The first saves the key to a file using DER encoding.

```
ByteQueue q1;
publicKey.DEREncodePublicKey(q1);

FileSink fs1("key_1.der", true);
q1.TransferTo(fs1);
```

The second saves the key to a string using DER encoding.

```
ByteQueue q2;
publicKey.DEREncodePublicKey(q2);

string key_2;
StringSink ss2(key_2);
q2.TransferTo(ss2);
```

You can use `BERDecodePublicKey` to recover the saved keys.

When using private keys, use `DEREncodePrivateKey` and `BERDecodePrivateKey`.